# What are the different methods to show Appium logs with Python in Windows?

Tags: python-3.x, appium, appium-android, python-appium, appium-desktop

I am trying to understand how to display the logs of Appium server for my python code.

First of all, I educated myself more about python logs And I made some experiments with 3 ways to sart Appium server before to come to you.

1)I tried by this way:

```
appium_service = AppiumService()
appium_service.start()
```

But I don't see any log. I guess I need to modify the python file of appium_service method.

2) So I tried to start appium server with command (I added the flag of scurity you suggested):

`os.system("start /B start cmd.exe @cmd /k appium --relaxed-security --log-timestamp --log appium.log -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4728")`

I could see some logs in terminal but not so much than Appium GUI server.
[image]

3) To show you the difference, I commented the lines of code which start Appium server, and I start it by hand with Appium GUI.
[image]

As you can see Appium GUI logs give more information to debug my code.

What should I do to display same info in Appium terminal than Appium GUI?
What should I do to display same info in 'appium_service.start()'  than Appium GUI?

I am working since 3 days to understand how can I show these logs without Appium GUI as my code need to run without any human interaction.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try with **logs = driver.get_log(‘server’);**

Comment: Thanks @Muzzamil I saw it on help. But where should I add this line of code? Under or before my capabilities? In the appium_service method code? Somewhere else?

Comment: Here is an example with good explanation for java and python https://appiumpro.com/editions/53